# loading data dynamically from mysql to Javascript table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts

I have this chart made with JavaScript(Canvas Js)

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxlRn.png)

the code is like the following

```
    <script>

        window.onload = function () {

            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                theme:"light2",
                animationEnabled: true,
                title:{
                    text: "PM"
                },
                axisY :{
                    includeZero: false,
                    title: "Heures",
                    suffix: "H"
                },
                toolTip: {
                    shared: "true"
                },
                legend:{
                    cursor:"pointer",
                    itemclick : toggleDataSeries
                },
                data: [
                    {
                        type: "spline",
                        showInLegend: true,
                        yValueFormatString: "##.00H",
                        name: "Preventive",
                        dataPoints: [
                            { label: "ABC", y: 2 },
                            { label: "DEF", y: 2 },
                            { label: "AAA", y: 2 }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        type: "spline",
                        showInLegend: true,
                        yValueFormatString: "##.00H",
                        name: "Curative",
                        dataPoints: [
                            { label: "ABC", y: 10 },
                            { label: "DEF", y: 2.27 },
                            { label: "AAA", y: 1.25 }
                        ]
                    }]
            });
            chart.render();

            function toggleDataSeries(e) {
                if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible ){
                    e.dataSeries.visible = false;
                } else {
                    e.dataSeries.visible = true;
                }
                chart.render();
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; max-width: 920px; margin: 0px auto;"></div>
<script src="../../canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you stated, the data i static.

However,when I wanted to load the data dynamically with mysql query

```
 dataPoints: [
                            <?php

                            $sq = "select machine,timediff from action_archiv_tech WHERE (date_tech BETWEEN '2018-09-10' AND '2018-10-06')";
                            $r = mysql_query($sq) or (die(mysql_error()));
                            while($tab = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
                            $machine = $tab['machine'];
                            $diff = $tab['diff'];
                            ?>
                            { label: "<?php echo $machine ?>", y: <?php echo $diff ?> }

                            <?php } ?>
                        ]
```

The page goes blank, Could you please help me figure out where I went wrong?

Comment: do not construct a json (or a js object/array) by string concatanation/echoing parts of it. Build an php array, json_encode that and echo that. (right now you're missing the `,` between the array items)

Comment: do not use mysql_* functions anymore. They are old, unsecure, deprecated and _removed_ from php7. Use mysqli or PDO

Comment: _"the page goes blank"_ -> switch on [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and/or view the server logs to find out why.

Comment: I started using pdo, this is an old project that needs some modofications, however I'm stuck to build an array for php using  json_encode

Comment: @jeff thanks a load dude for your time & help, I will try what you suggested and report

Comment: 1st move the php code to a different spot in your script (out of the javascript). 2nd in our while: `$data[] = ["label"=>$machine, "y"=>$diff];`. 3rd , verify you got correct data in `$data`. 4th in javascript part echo that data like so: `dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>`

Comment: I tried this, the data loads dynamically, the machines show in the axis X  however the time (axis y) is loaded aswell but it's not represented in the graph

Comment: [code][1]


[results][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIAwf.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyIZM.png

Comment: then have a look what the parsed `dataPoints: [???]` actually looks like (in your browser: view source)

Comment: Array ( [label] => H4N [y] => 0.9000 ) ,Array ( [label] => HB8 [y] => 0.6333 ) ...

Comment: I converted the time to hours

Comment: that's not the output of a `json_encode`d array

Comment: Thank you so so so much dude for your time and your follow up, you have no idea how much you helped me, I found this Documentation online https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319852640_Creation_of_Charts_with_PHP_HTML5_and_Javascript#pf15 It was very helpful as well

Comment: I hope life brings you joy